# Chrome for Android HTML 5 background audio stops

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-audio, background-audio

I'm writing a webapp that uses the HTML 5 audio tag to play back mp3 Shoutcast streams.

With the stock Android browser (and Safari on iOS), I can lock the phone and the sound keeps playing indefinitely. With Android Chrome (I'm running v31 on Android 4.1.2), if I lock the screen or background the app to do other stuff, the audio plays for a couple of minutes and then dies.

Is this a known issue with Chrome or am I missing something?

Comment: This was fixed a while ago and should still be working... I imagine the process is getting killed.  Do you have a sample that I can try.

Comment: Hi Paul @Kinlan - that would be much appreciated. I do have a demo but it's not for public consumption. Can I email you or can you drop me a mail via info [at] radiotuna [dot] com please? Cheers

Comment: The same thing is happening on html5.grooveshark.com with normal html5 audio playback of individual files or in a "broadcast" which is a shoutcast style stream. The problem is present even in Chrome 32 beta.

Comment: I'll check. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Might be related to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121898 ?